# painting on glassPane is slow

Tags: java, performance, swing, paint, glasspane

I'm building a domino game in java and I am using modified rectangle2d's to draw my tiles. To drag a tile I use mouse events to change the tiles coordinates and redraw the JPanel.

This all works great and very smooth, until I start using the frames glassPane, I use the glassPane to be able to drag a tile from one JPanel to another.

It works, but rendering is quite slow when I paint on the glassPane. I've tried to use clipping when repainting, but it makes no difference.

Does anyone have an idea?

thnx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems when a glassPane is visible on your RootPaneContainer, all repaint events behind the GlassPane have their clip set to fill the entire RootPaneContainer. This may be overriding your manually specified clip rect.